# capistrano deploy_via copy not excluding files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I use a dummy SCM and copy strategy  to deploy my Rails 3 application. To make it faster, I'd like to exclude some files from the copy (e.g. logs). I set following options in my `config/deploy.rb`:

```
set :scm, :none 
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_exclude, "**/*.log"
```

However, it seems to copy logs during deployment. What did I wrong?

Comment: maybe you didnt specify the right path

Comment: @Lichtamberg: `"**/*.log"` seems to be OK, I've also tried `"log/"`.

Comment: try maybe the absolute file path?

Comment: Have you tried tracing capistrano output of command that is responsible fo rcopying files? It should be visible by default.

Comment: Also -- I don't know what language of patterns is used by capistrano here, but documentation uses example `.git/*`. Have you tried `log/*`?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/v2.15.4/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/scm/none.rb As can be seen from the source, the `copy_exclude` setting is not respected when using `:scm none`

Answer (score 0):

refer to: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/5/2/capistrano-2-3-0.html

for Capistrano 2, you should use copy_exclude:

```
set :repository, "."
set :scm, :none
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_exclude, ['tmp', 'log']
```

for Capistrano 3, (using the gem: capistrano-scm-copy), see this: 
(https://github.com/wercker/capistrano-scm-copy/issues/6)

```
set :exclude_dir, "deploy"
```